# Installing Oracle 10g with Apex 4.0

Tags: oracle10g, oracle-apex

I installed Oracle 10g Express Client. I have Apex 2.1 right now. I tried to follow the instructions in this video (http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xf2HEtNmHmU) to upgrade to Apex 4.0, but when I enter my password in cmd, it says TNS protocol adapter error, so I could not proceed. Please help me.

Also, can I create an application in apex 2.1 with charts implementation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to install the full Oracle Express Database (not just the client).
You could try the 11g Express Edition beta which has 4.0 already installed

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/express-edition/11gxe-beta-download-302519.html